# SAS format in data step

Tags: sas

I have a WORK dataset with more than 30 columns but only 2 columns out of them are date fields. (Start date and End date). I want the date format in the permanent dataset to be in date. and not in yymmdd10. which is the current format in work dataset. When I used the below code, the two date fields are taking first two positions. I dont want to reorder the positions and at the same time dont want to mention the format with all 30+ columns. Could someone please help me if there is any way for this?

```
data DLR.DEALER; 
set  work.dealer_invoices; * this dataset contains more than 30 columns; 
format start_dt end_dt date.; 
run;
```

I could not find any solution for this on our site. Any help is highly appreciated than just asking me to mention all the columns in the format statement :) Thanks in advance.

Comment: I wouldn't think the `format` statement would have any effect on variable ordering as it is after the `set` statement. I can't replicate your problem with the information given.

Comment: Same, can't replicate your issue. If you can replicate it, I recommend opening up a ticket with tech support.

Comment: @DWal thats really surprising. I think, then I should raise a ticket. Thank you

Comment: Are you sure that you're looking at the column names and not column labels when viewing the results?  Are you getting any notes/warnings about variables being uninitialized etc?

Comment: @RobertPenridge, Yes I am 100% sure. I displayed the contents using proc contents data=work.dealer_invoices; run; then the columns start_end and end_date are displayed as 1 and 2 under the section "Alphabetic List of Variables and Attributes"

Comment: Alphabetic List of Variables and Attributes
# Variable Type Len Format Informat
5 vendor_sk Num 8 BEST12. BEST32.
3 vendor_type Char 1 $1. $1.
4 dealer_id Num 8 BEST12. BEST32.
1 start_dt Num 8 DATE. YYMMDD10.
2 end_dt Num 8 DATE. YYMMDD10.

Comment: And you checked the log to make sure it ran? And didn't have the dataset open (effectively locking it and preventing changes)?  Did you try restarting your SAS session?  I think I'd have to see this bug replicated to believe it.

Comment: I do not relly get this. You are mentioning that you do not want `start_dt` and `end_dt` to be the first columns in your `DLR.DEALER` data set, right?

Then you belive  that the `format` line changes the order from the original order in `work.dealer_invoices`, but in the same time you say that the result of `proc contents data=work.dealer_invoices; run;`  lists `start_dt` and `end_dt` as numer one and two respecitvely in `Alphabetic List of Variables and Attributes`. Does this not mean that they are first in this dataset from the beginning? Ergo, no change in order.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Certainly the format statement shouldn't have any impact on ordering given its location.

A workaround would be to use `PROC DATASETS` to change the format instead of in the data step.

You also could "mention all columns" fairly easily.

```
proc sql;
  select name into :namelist separated by ' '
  from dictionary.columns
  where libname='WORK' and memname='DEALER_INVOICES'
  order by varnum;
quit;
```

then

```
data DLR.DEALER;
  retain &namelist;
  set work.dealer_invoices;
  format...;
run;
```